# Iteration counter not incrementing

Tags: c++

I wrote a program in c++ to print all the primes up to 100, but it just writes `"hello world"`, and then hangs. Why is that?

```
#include <iostream>

bool is_prime(int num)
{
    if(num == 1)
    {
        return false;
    }
    for(int i = 2; i < num; i++)
    {
        if(num % i == 0)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

int increase(int i)
{
    return i++;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << "hello world!!" << std::endl;
    int i = 1;
    while(i < 100)
    {
        i = increase(i);
        if(is_prime(i))
        {
            std::cout << i << " is prime" << std::endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: why not put the `i++` (or `++i` for the matter) in the actual loop?

Comment: @cabellicar123 probably in case he wants to easily change the increment amount of `i`?

Comment: @Josh maybe but then I still think an `i += x` would be clearer.

Comment: @OP What's so special about 2 and 3?

Comment: does it really keep writing "hello world!!"? That should only happen once each time your run the program.

Comment: @craq - I think he means it prints "hello world!!" once, then loops infinitely with no further output. At least, that's what the code says.

Comment: @Vladp - you obviously know how a `for` loop works, since you're using one in the other method. So why not use `for (int i = 2; i <= 100; i++)` (and get rid of the increment, etc.) instead of `while (i < 100)`?

Comment: A simple debug session would have shown that `i` did not increase.

Comment: I'm sure there will be a sample in a textbook similar to this to show the difference of `++i` and `i++`?

Comment: Why has this question received so much attention - both in terms of up votes and responses?

Comment: @Pradhan and favourites!

Comment: @craq I have edited that - I think we can assume it does not keep printing "hello world" judging from the code, and the accepted answer. GalacticCowboy is probably correct about what OP meant, so I have hopefully made it more clear.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`return i++;` this statement would return the original value of `i`, not the incremented one.

You need `return ++i;` or `return i + 1` *(thanks to [@interjay](https://stackoverflow.com/users/189205/interjay) for pointing that)*. The later `return i + 1;` makes it clear that only the return value matters, and not the new value of `i`.

The effect of post increment `i++` would be visible on the next line *(or usage of `i`)*.

Not really sure, if you need a separate method for incrementing your variable `i`, you can do that at in your while loop.

```
 while(i < 100)
    {

        if(is_prime(i))
        {
            std::cout << i << " is prime" << std::endl;
        }
        i++;
    }
```

You can also use a `for` loop, instead of `while` since you are working with a range of values.

```
for(i = 1; i < 100; i++)
{
    if(is_prime(i))
    {
        std::cout << i << " is prime" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually, `return i+1` is better than either because it makes it clear that the returned value is the only thing that matters, not the new value of `i`.

Comment: @interjay, yes that is definitely better and shows the intent.

Comment: I'd also suggest getting into the habit of preferring preincrement to postincrement.  (`++i` vs `i++`, and assuming you need to use the increment operator to begin with).  While in the case of an `int` it is likely not going to matter (yay, optimizer), more complex types may require non-trivial effort to return the preincremented value.  If you have no interest in that value, then why cause the program to make the extra effort?

Answer (score 10):

Try this:

```
int increase(int i)
{
    return ++i;
}
```

to get the incremented value of `i` else you will get the original value of i which will lead you to infinite loop.

The better approach would be to use(for clarity):

```
int increase(int i)
{
    return i+1;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You are calling `i++`. i++ remembers what value `i` had and returns that. Try to call `++i`.

Answer (score 3):

`return i++;` returns `i` then increase `i` in function stack,
use `return ++i;` instead.

remember doing something on X++ first do something then increase X.

Answer (score 2):

the problem is that ur increase function keeps returning 1. To fix the issue, change `i++` to `++i`, the second one modify `i` by adding 1 before returning

Answer (score 2):

why create a function to increase i. just i = i+1;

The problem is with i++; should be change to ++i;

i++ evaluates i and then increments i, whereas it should be increment i before you evaluate..

Another problem start from 5 instead of 2 since you already handled the case

```
bool is_prime(int num)
{
    if(num == 1)
    {
        return false;
    }
    if(num == 2 || num == 3)
    {
        return true;
    }
    for(int i = 5; i < num; i++)
    {
        if(num % i == 0)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Another way of doing prime numbers:

```
bool is_prime(int num)
{
  while(1)
  {
     int div = x-1;
     if(x%div==0)
      return false;
     else
     if(div != 1)
         div--;
     else
       return false;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I++ increments I after executing the line. ++I increments I before executing the line.

You may check operator precedence (it works for c++ also)

[c operator precedence](http://www.difranco.net/compsci/C_Operator_Precedence_Table.htm)

Note 2 explains why return I++ does not work.